# mfc how to write commands in command window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, pipe, windows-console

I need to write some commands in command window using C++ code. How to implement it. I have tried with `CreateProcess` function but it seems some wrong in it. Please refer my code below:

```
 STARTUPINFO sInfo = {0};
sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = {0};

CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",""0,0,TRUE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);
```

It opens the command window successfully. My doubt is how to write command through code in it.

Comment: You could pass the `/c` or `/k` parameter to *cmd.exe*, see *cmd.exe /?* for more help about using these options. The better option would be to execute the commands you want directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you need **not** to create a separate process just to write text output to a console window.

It depends what and how you want to write. You may create a console application itself, or **create a console** itself, and attach to the current process. You need to use **pipes** for the same and redirect the output to given pipe (i.e. send data to pipe). At the other end of pipe, you will read the text/buffer and render the output wherever you would like to.

These articles may help:

- [Console Output from GUI program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10073/Console-Output-from-a-GUI-program)
- [Real time Console Output redirection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection)

Since your question is not very clear, this is just assumption. 
Or, are you playing with the console itself - like changing colors, dimension etc?